# Macro Excel Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have a problem with looping a Macro in excel. 
I have a Data base where i need to add a row above each unique value and copy the value below into the new row.
untill now i have come up with this:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+K
' FindNextValueChangeInColumn Macro
'
 Dim currentValue As String
 Dim compareValue As String

 currentValue = ActiveCell.Value

 If (currentValue = "") Then
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
 Else
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   compareValue = ActiveCell.Value

   Do While currentValue = compareValue
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     compareValue = ActiveCell.Value
   Loop

   Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Selection.Copy
   ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial
 End If

 Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This macro does the job, but i dont want to press ctrl-k 4000 times every time an update is necessary. Anyone knows how to loop this macro ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap a for loop around the code you want executed:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+K
' FindNextValueChangeInColumn Macro
'

'-------Loop from 1 to 4000------------
Dim loopy
For loopy = 1 to 4000 'Loop 4000 times
'--------------------------------------

    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim compareValue As String

    currentValue = ActiveCell.Value

    If (currentValue = "") Then
      Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Else
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      compareValue = ActiveCell.Value

      Do While currentValue = compareValue
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        compareValue = ActiveCell.Value
      Loop

      Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Selection.Copy
      ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
      Selection.PasteSpecial
    End If

'-----Don't forget this line-----
Next loopy
'--------------------------------

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use a while loop to loop until the currentValue = "":

```
Do  
    currentValue = ActiveCell.Value

    If (currentValue = "") Then
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        compareValue = ActiveCell.Value

        Do While currentValue = compareValue
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            compareValue = ActiveCell.Value
        Loop

        Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial
    End If

Loop While currentValue <> ""
```